# Download image for a product in magento 2

Tags: magento2, product-images

We need to download an image when customer clicks download button. we have coupons for products.for every product there is a coupon associated , coupon is image and in that image coupon code is there, how can i achieve this, as the coupon is for every product , do i need to create an attribute in product level ,if so what is the type of that attribute i need to create and how can i show it on frontend so the user can download it.please guide me how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

> Create `New Attribute` for `Image Upload` in Admin Side.
>
> After Create That Attribute Display in **Product Detail Page.**

**Reference Link :-**

[How to Display Custom Attribute](https://www.dckap.com/blog/display-custom-attribute-value-product-viewlist-page-magento-2/)